# Need a more efficient LINQ statement or way to query SQL Server CE using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a method that queries a SQL Server CE database using Entity Framework for an Point Of Service application and prints the results. The code I am using works but when the database grows in size the method takes a lot longer to execute. I think this is because the database is being queried multiple times to achieve the desired result. What I really want to do is query the database once and store the results in memory and then run all the other queries against the data stored in memory.

The method predominantly needs to query the database to find today's transactions (ZTotaled == null) and then print the number of transactions and total sales for every 30mins of the trading day.

The code I am using looks like this...

```
var ztotal = from z in context.Transactions
where z.ZTotaled == null
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid, z.ZTotaled, z.DateTime }; 


var ztotal2 = from z in ztotal
where z.ZTotaled == null && z.DateTime.Hour == 18 && z.DateTime.Minute < 30
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid };


totalPeople = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.NumerPeople);
totalPaid = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.PricePaid);


sb2.Append(string.Format("{0}{1,10}{2,16}", "18.00 - 18.30", totalPeople.ToString(), totalPaid.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);

ztotal2 = from z in ztotal
where z.ZTotaled == null && z.DateTime.Hour == 18 && z.DateTime.Minute >= 30
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid };

totalPeople = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.NumerPeople);
totalPaid = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.PricePaid);

sb2.Append(string.Format("{0}{1,10}{2,16}", "18.30 - 19.00", totalPeople.ToString(), totalPaid.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);

ztotal2 = from z in ztotal
where z.ZTotaled == null && z.DateTime.Hour == 19 && z.DateTime.Minute < 30
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid };

totalPeople = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.NumerPeople);
totalPaid = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.PricePaid);

sb2.Append(string.Format("{0}{1,10}{2,16}", "19.00 - 19.30", totalPeople.ToString(), totalPaid.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);

ztotal2 = from z in ztotal
where z.ZTotaled == null && z.DateTime.Hour == 19 && z.DateTime.Minute >= 30
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid };

totalPeople = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.NumerPeople);
totalPaid = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.PricePaid);

sb2.Append(string.Format("{0}{1,10}{2,16}", "19.30 - 20.00", totalPeople.ToString(), totalPaid.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);

ztotal2 = from z in ztotal
where z.ZTotaled == null && z.DateTime.Hour == 20 && z.DateTime.Minute < 30
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid };

totalPeople = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.NumerPeople);
totalPaid = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.PricePaid);

sb2.Append(string.Format("{0}{1,10}{2,16}", "20.00 - 20.30", totalPeople.ToString(), totalPaid.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
```

Could someone please point me in the direction to making this code more efficient?

Many thanks

James

Comment: consider sending the query once (sort by DateTime, filter out what's not needed on the server) and do the categorization on the client

Comment: Code Review may be a better place for this question, Stack Overflow focuses more on troubleshooting and problems.

Comment: Thanks... but as i already stated in the question: _"What I really want to do is query the database once and store the results in memory and then run all the other queries against the data stored in memory"._  What im not sure of is how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the performance problem i was having was due to deferred execution.  By adding .ToList() to the first LINQ query it was forced to execute the query immediately into a list of objects.  All further queries were then performed against this list in memory.

```
var ztotal = (from z in context.Transactions
where z.ZTotaled == null
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid, z.ZTotaled, z.DateTime }).ToList(); 


var ztotal2 = from z in ztotal
where z.ZTotaled == null && z.DateTime.Hour == 18 && z.DateTime.Minute < 30
select new { z.NumerPeople, z.PricePaid };


totalPeople = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.NumerPeople);
totalPaid = ztotal2.Sum(o => o.PricePaid);


sb2.Append(string.Format("{0}{1,10}{2,16}", "18.00 - 18.30", totalPeople.ToString(),      totalPaid.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
```